# How can I use the Showcase View in a ListView Item in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, showcaseview

How can I use the Showcase View in a ListView Item in Flutter?

I have a ListView, I want to show a showcase in any item of this list. is there any way to do this in flutter?

I guess the [showcaseview](https://pub.dev/packages/showcaseview) package doesn't support **ListView** items. (or I couldn't)

Like this;

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I Solved.

Example :

```
ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (cont, index) {
          return index == 0 ? ShowCase(key: accountItemShowCase,
                                       title: 'Başlık',
                                       description:'Açıklama', child:bankAccountItem(idx)) : bankAccountItem(index);
        },
        itemCount: items.length,
      )
```